# ¿Por qué no puedo usar curb en Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

Me encuentro con este problema. Instalé CURB en ruby on rails haciendo `gem install curb` pero cuando ejecuto el codigo me sale

```
LoadError
cannot load such file -- curb
```

Mi controlador es:

```
require "curb"
class VeiculosController < ApplicationController
  skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token

  def api

    url = "URL_DE_LA_API_A_LLAMAR"

    data = {
      veiculos: params[:veiculos]
    }

    response = Curl::Easy.http_post( url ) do |http|
      http.headers["Accept"] = "application/json"
      http.headers["Content-Type"] = "application/json"
      http.post_body = data.to_json
    end
    
    response_api( response )
  end
end
```

Es extraño, tambien probé con `excon` y el mismo problema. ¿A que se debe el problema que tengo?

Tambien probé lo [siguiente](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33427371/9711433) que encontré por aqui pero igual no me resolvió nada, el mismo problema.

Mi version de Ruby es: `ruby 2.7.1p83`
Mi version de Rails es: `Rails 6.0.3.2`

Answer (score 1):

Si solo hiciste `gem install curb`, no debería estar integrada del todo dentro de tu proyecto rails.
Prueba agregando `gem 'curb'` a tu `Gemfile` y luego ejecutar `bundle install`.

Comment: Si, hice eso y aún tengo el mismo problema. Tambien con `require_relative`

Comment: @Jonathan y al instalar la gema ¿te arroja algún error? Al ejecutar `gem list` ¿sale la gema como ya instalada?

Answer (score 0):

resolví. Lo primero que hice fue `gem update --system` y luego elimine la gema `curb` e instalé la gema `httparty`, luego lo agregué a `Gemfile` y luego ejecuté el `bundle install`. Con eso fue suficiente.